# How to select one attribute in object array

Tags: python, arrays, object, pickle

I have a problem in select one attribute off one obj in an array. This is the array (I try to send this with a pickle but I can't use):

```
items = []
results = service.files().list(corpora="drive",driveId=map_project_ids[project],pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken,supportsAllDrives=True,includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",fields="nextPageToken, files(id,createdTime,name,parents)").execute()
items.extend(results.get('files', []))
pickle.dump(items,open(f"results_{PROJECT}.pkl","wb"))
```

after get this data form google drive (76k folders), i need to send a specific information, like id, parent, and created time of a folder in array.

The items array structure is:

```
[{
    'parents': ['1H7cY0cncy5fXt7of0xxN3jdTmzk'], 
    'id': '1UDqOjxiZFPdY3goFPSecc53xOW4', 
    'name': '20620', 
    'createdTime': '2023-06-19T15:51:15.280Z'
 }, 
 {
    'parents': ['1kq6FBSvhIZqyQASntqOmL6AQEak'], 
    'id': '1CPDgaPOF3Kg4Ds26GpyxuJblQ3', 
    'name': '230620', 
    'createdTime': '2023-06-19T15:51:02.397Z'
 }]
```

How can I access only the id, parent, and createdTime off each entry in this array to storage in a DB?

obs: I'm using google colab.

I try:

```
for i in items:
  salvarDB (i.parents, i.id, i.createdTime)
```

Comment: `i` is a dictionary, so it should be `i['parents'], i['id'], i['createdTime']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your previous code is that you were trying to access the attributes of each item using dot notation (`i.parents`, `i.id`, `i.createdTime`), as if the items in the array were `objects`. However, the items in the array are dictionaries, and dictionary keys are accessed using square brackets (`[]`) instead of dot notation.

Try this code

```
for item in items:
    parents = item['parents']
    folder_id = item['id']
    created_time = item['createdTime']
    salvarDB(parents, folder_id, created_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). By passing to it the keys the you need it returns a callable object that can be applied to an iterable object.

PS it works with list, tuples,... as well.

```
from operator import itemgetter

keys = "parents", "id", "createdTime"
for record in map(itemgetter(*keys), items):
    salvarDB(*record)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I was able to solve that problem.